# clever-turning cicada-ticking sun chasers

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

"...Even in the dark they fretted, feeling the stars bite like summer flies as they migrated overhead. They built shelters to block out the sight of their passing. This only succeeded in making things dimmer; the unseen lion in the tall grass is still a lion that exists. **Clever-turning cicada-ticking sun-chasers they tied together so that they would always know where she was**, clinging to the sun’s fiery tail like frightened calves."

The excerpt above has been taken from Brooke Bolander's novella, *The Only Harmless Great Thing in the World*. She is referring to human beings, and criticizing their fondness of light and fear of the dark, but I cannot figure out the meaning of the part in bold. Could someone please interpret that sentence? What does clever-turning, cicada-ticking mean? Who ties who together? To know where the SUN was? Please explain. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Clever-turning cicada-ticking sun-chasers` perhaps refers to clocks; they are the devices which turn cleverly, which tick, which chase the sun (i.e. cling to its fiery tail)

Comment: @shivams I agree, and perhaps "tied together" is a poetic way of saying "built". Only Brooke Bolander would know for sure.

Comment: @ckok It'd be difficult for us to tell by simply this paragraph. Could you add a little more text preceding and succeeding it? Or, give more context on what's going on in the pages where this part appears?

Comment: It's poetic. Lots of possible interpretations. Cicada-ticking makes no sense to me. Cicadas don't tick to me, they buzz or sing or call or chirp, but ticking like a clock... that's a very sick cicada.

Comment: Here the broader context is about human beings' building a factory for producing radium clock dials so that American soldiers can tell the time in the dark, but there dials were painted by Girls Who used radium to Paint them and eventually many of these Girls got poisoned and died. Now the clock imagery fits perfectly here. Thank you